# read a range between two rows with the same value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to read the last added range of data ("A10:C15") delimited by a custom row (i.e. row 1, row 9) that will dynamically get added into the sheet.

So far I've just managed to read the entire sheet with `getRange("A1:C15")` but I cannot use only values in range "A10:C15" (and any other newly added range).

[image: image1]

Comment: Please explain the characteristics of row 1 and 9. I presume their location is variable.  Is there anything unique that can be use to find the last section.  Like they alway begin with three tildes or something like that.

Comment: all cells from row 1 and 9 have the same content: xxx. The location of the rows is variable. I am trying to figure out a way to identify them based on cell content (but i have no idea if that's even possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get all the data
- Do a reverse for-loop and get data up to the delimiter
- Loop starts from `values.length-1` to `0`

```
const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
  lastSet = [];
for( let i = values.length-1; i>=0 ; i-- ){
  if (values[i][0] === "xxx" ) break;
  lastSet.push(values[i])
}
console.info({lastSet});
```

Comment: this did the trick, i only had to do the for loop from values.length-1 (to avoid the TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'))

Comment: @Alex Glad to help. Feel free to edit the answer.